# How to make Twitter Bootstrap's <pre> blocks scroll horizontally?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, horizontal-scrolling, pre

Per the examples https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/content/code/#code-blocks, bootstrap only supports vertically-scrollable and word-wrapped `<pre>` blocks out of the box. How do I make it so that I have horizontally-scrollable, unwrapped code blocks instead?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The trick is that bootstrap overrides *both* the `white-space` and the CSS3 `word-wrap` attributes for the `<pre>` element. To achieve horizontal scrolling, ensure there's this in your CSS:

```
pre {
  overflow: auto;
  word-wrap: normal;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

Comment: I would not recommend over-riding bootstrap classes. Instead I would create a new CSS file called eg. bootstrap-extras.css and define a new class eg. pre-x-scrollable (similar to their pre-scrollable) that applies your behavior above. That way you don't get clashing classes when you upgrade bootstrap from source in the future.

Comment: for bootstrap3: `pre code` and remove the `overflow:auto`

Comment: Just a heads up, `word-wrap` is [changing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap) to `overflow-wrap` in CSS3.

Comment: Setting `white-space: pre-wrap` was the trick for me to have the pre block actually wrap as desired

Answer (score 25):

This worked for me:

```css
pre {
    overflow-x: auto;
}
pre code {
    overflow-wrap: normal;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Comment: [`overflow-wrap`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-text/#overflow-wrap) still has [spotty implementation](http://css3clickchart.com/#overflow-wrap).  For now, you should use the older [`word-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap) which is supported by all browsers.

Comment: @KyleMit For now, you should use both. Then, when `overflow-wrap` starts gaining support you won't have to go back and update all of your CSS.

Answer (score 16):

I keep coming back to this answer when I start new projects and have to read through comments to remember, oh yea, don't override the bootstrap class and don't forget overflow-wrap, etc...

So you have the stock `pre-scrollable`, which is vertical only scrolling, you may also want:

### Horizontal only scrolling

```
.pre-x-scrollable {
    overflow: auto;
    -ms-word-wrap: normal;
    word-wrap: normal;
    overflow-wrap: normal;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

### Vertical and Horizontal scrolling

```
.pre-xy-scrollable {
    overflow: auto;
    -ms-word-wrap: normal;
    word-wrap: normal;
    overflow-wrap: normal;
    white-space: pre;
    max-height: 340px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Newer versions of Bootstrap apply styles to both `pre` and `code` that wrap words. Adding this to my stylesheet fixed the issue for me:

```
pre code {
        white-space: pre;
        word-wrap: normal;
}
```