# Difficulty getting pre and code tags to scroll rather than wrap

Tags: css, syntax-highlighting, highlight, pre

[My website](http://matthewdaly.co.uk/) is built using a static site generator I created myself, and uses Bootstrap for the layout. I'm using Highlight.js for the syntax highlighting (running server-side as part of the build process) and it's working pretty well. However, one thing has stumped me.

I would like the code tags to scroll when a line is too wide, rather than wrapping to the next line. Usually, I believe this can normally be done by styling the `<pre>` tags with `white-space: nowrap`, but that doesn't work here, and everything I've tried either has no effect or just pushes everything to the left.

Can anyone else see what the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stumbled across the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16420440/63717) in the end:

```
pre {
    overflow-x: auto;
}
pre code {
    overflow-wrap: normal;
    word-wrap: normal;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you add the following attribute at the declaration, it's will be fine.

```
useBR:false
```

Comment: I'll give that a try tonight.

Comment: No, this doesn't make any difference.